# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Всем привет. Есть два скрипта на python 3. 
Первый скрипт работает без проблем(цель - собрать необходимые ссылки со страницы):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
from itertools import groupby

r = requests.get('http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/ammann/index.htm')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
link = soup.find('div', class_='elenco').find_all('a', href = re.compile('azienda'))
links = [i.get('href') for i in link]

new_links = [el for el, _ in groupby(links)]

for i in new_links:
    print('http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/ammann/' + i)
```

Второй скрипт - это дополненный первый скрипт, его цель - из входного файл прочесть данные (file_1), затем перейти на указанные адреса и собрать нужную информацию(т.е. еще ссылки). НО, появляется ошибка(заголовок вопроса). Вопрос: в чем проблема? Почему-то код страницы, который получает переменная **soup**, в разных скриптах различен, но переменная **r** получает одинаковый адрес.
Второй(проблемный) скрипт:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
from itertools import groupby

file_1 = 'links.txt'
file_2 = 'links2.txt'
myfile_1 = open(file_1, mode = 'r', encoding = 'ascii')
myfile_2 = open(file_2, mode = 'w', encoding = 'ascii')

for link in myfile_1:

    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

    url = soup.find('div', class_='elenco').find_all('a', href = re.compile('azienda'))
    print(url)
    urls = [i.get('href') for i in url]

    new_urls = [el for el, _ in groupby(urls)]

    for i in new_urls:
        myfile_2.write('http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/ammann/' + i)
```

Первые три строки в links.txt: http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/ammann/index.htm
http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/astra/index.htm
http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/atlas/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил, сам ответил. 
Во-первых нужно добавить в r = requests.get(link.**strip()**), что позволяет убрать перевод строки ('\n') после каждой строки. Во-вторых добавить исключения, если ссылки будет 'битая'. В-третьих сделать актуальную конкатенацию строк для получаемых ссылок при записи в файл.
Рабочий код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
from itertools import groupby

file_1 = 'links.txt'
file_2 = 'links2.txt'
myfile_1 = open(file_1, mode = 'r', encoding = 'ascii')
myfile_2 = open(file_2, mode = 'w', encoding = 'ascii')

for link in myfile_1:
    try:
        print(link)
        r = requests.get(link.strip())
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

        url = soup.find('div', class_='elenco').find_all('a', href = re.compile('azienda'))
        #print(url)
        urls = [i.get('href') for i in url]

        new_urls = [el for el, _ in groupby(urls)]

        for i in new_urls:
            url_base = 'http://www.mmtitalia.it/directory_edile/rivenditori_macchine/'
            uls_current = link.split('/')[5]
            myfile_2.write(url_base + uls_current + '/' + i + '\n')

    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Буду благодарен за комментарии по улучшению кода, ибо сам только недавно начал изучение python.